# Create a Split View ViewController

Tags: iphone

Fairly new to iPhone/Cocoa development, so I'm having difficulty adjusting.

I want to create a ViewController that has two separate subViews. Kind of how the TabViewController/NavigationController is set up, but I want to be able to control what's in the other portion as well (not to mention sizing, etc.). Either orientation is fine (top/bottom) or (left/right).

```
+--------+   +----+----+
|  top   |   | l  |  r |
|        |   | e  |  i |
+--------+   | f  |  g |
|        |   | t  |  h |
| bottom |   |    |  t |
+--------+   +----+----+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a subclass of ViewController and add three properties:

FirstView, SecondView, isVertical

These three properties will in general be enough to create a simple split view. The consumer would be responsible for setting up those properties, and inside of your ViewController's loadView method, you would add both of those views to a new view, which you would then assign to the "view" property of the UIViewController.

That's really all there is to it for a *extremely limited* feature set Split ViewController. The rest of the features would mostly likely just customize how the views are sized and positioned.

Hope this helps, and please open source it :)

Comment: I was looking for something I could manipulate in Interface Builder, but I just went ahead and manipulated the stuff programmatically. It'll wind up being easier.